# how can I sum multiple columns in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can I do this in laravel eloquent, i tried doing this but It gives me error.. how can I sum two columns in laravel `SUM( column1 + column2 )`

```
FileDBConsistency::join('Servers', 'Servers.srv_id', '=' , 'FileDBConsistency.srv_id')
        ->sum('SUM( FileDBConsistency.dbconflict + FileDBConsistency.fileconflict ) as sum')
        ->get( $array )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You don't need to `get()` the results of a `sum()` operation.
2. In order to sum multiple columns, you'll want to use `DB::raw()`.

Here's a Tinker example from the database I have open:

```
[1] > Priority::sum(DB::raw('priority + priority'));
// '2768'
```